# How to write mock for Model method that calls a mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mailer

I'm trying to write a test for my Message model. This model has a method 'send_message':

```
def send_message
   ContactMailer.contact_mail(self.name, self.email, self.text, self.ip).deliver
end
```

In my rspec file I have the following:

```
mailer = double(ContactMailer)
mailer.should_receive(:contact_mail)

FactoryGirl.build(:message).send_message
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: mailer.should_receive(:contact_mail)
   (Double ContactMailer).contact_mail(any args)
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Any idea? Could it be because I'm not taking `.deliver` into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the issue is that you haven't told RSpec that `ContactMailer` should receive that message. The argument to `double` is just a way to "name" the double for documentation purposes, as discussed in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks

You actually don't need a double in this case, as you can set the expectation directly on the `ContactMailer` class as follows:

```
ContactMailer.should_receive(:contact_mail)
```